# Why does print work with awk but echo doesn't?

Tags: awk, echo

To sum it up....

This works:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; }
{ print  $1  $3  $5; }' /etc/passwd
```

But this doesn't:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; }
{ echo  $1  $3  $5; }' /etc/passwd
```

I would like to know why.

Comment: `print` is a keyword in *Awk*; `echo` is a shell word. Your examples are Awk examples that happen to be run in a shell...

Comment: 1. because `awk` doesn't have an `echo` keyword, it has `print` instead.  2. because `awk` and `sh` (or `bash`/`dash`/`zsh`/`ksh` etc. and `perl`. and `python`) are different scripting languages and have different keywords and syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of `awk` execution is: `pattern { action statements }`

> Actions
>       Action statements are enclosed in braces, { and }.  Action statements
>          consist of the usual assignment, conditional, and looping statements
>          found in most languages.  The operators, control statements, and
>          input/output statements available are patterned after those in C.

- **`print` is I/O statement of `awk`**.

  From manpage:

  ```
  print                 Print the current record.  The output record is terminated with the value of ORS.
  ```
- Visit [**manual>The print Statement**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print.html#Print):

  > The print Statement
  >
  > Use the print statement to produce output with simple, standardized formatting. You specify only the strings or numbers to print, in a list separated by commas. They are output, separated by single spaces, followed by a newline. The statement looks like this:
  >
  > ```
  > print item1, item2, …
  > ```

---

Visit `man awk` for more details.

Also note that:

```
PATTERNS AND ACTIONS
       AWK is a line-oriented language.  The pattern comes  first,  and  then  the  action.   Action  statements  are
       enclosed  in  {  and  }.  Either the pattern may be missing, or the action may be missing, but, of course, not
       both.  If the pattern is missing, the action is executed for every single record of input.  A  missing  action
       is equivalent to

              { print }

       which prints the entire record.
```

---

**`awk` doesn't have `echo` keyword/statement.**

```
$ man awk | grep echo | wc -l
0
```