# Problem using tail and awk to monitor log and execute a command

Tags: awk, logs, raspberry-pi, monitoring, tail

I want to monitor a log file in real time, and execute some commands when some sentences appear in the log.

I searched this site (and many other sites) and these are what I tried:

```
tail -f /var/log/omxlog | awk '/player_new/ { "echo hello" }'
```

or

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -F /var/log/omxlog | awk '/player_new/ { "echo hello" }'
```

But they don't work. Whenever I run these commands, it begins to wait, but although I'm sure the log file changes, it doesn't print echo hello; actually it doesn't do anything. Just waiting :D

So, what should I do!?

(System: Raspberry Pi. OS: Raspbian)

Comment: My first thought is to open another shell and manually add the trigger text to the target file. Or set up a test file and target that.

Comment: refer to [How to “filter” a tail output throug awk and grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164964/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Archemar has the correct solution for your exact question in his answer.

However it's clear that you probably want to execute regular commands, like you would in bash, since you used "echo hello".

In that case, it will be much easier if you stay within bash, and then you have its full power at your disposal (Instead of having to learn how to do that within awk), I think you will find this much more flexible and easy to work with.

bash method, in a one liner:

```
tail .... | while read ; do [[ "{REPLY}" =~ player_new ]] && echo hello ; done
```

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail_log()
{
    tail -f "${1}"
    # or use stdbuf here instead
}

do_player_new()
{
  local log_line="${1}"
  echo "hello"
}

do_something_else()
{
  local log_line="${1}"
  echo "example: line was ${1}"
}

process_match()
{
  local full_line="${1}"

  case "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  #this bash_rematch array holds the part of the line that matched the () in the pattern 
  in
    player_new)      do_player_new "${full_line}";;
    something_else)  do_something_else "${full_line}";;
    another_example) do_another_example "${full_line}";;
  esac

  #or you could actually just execute this:
  # "do_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${full_line}"
}

process_log()
{
  local logfile="${1}"
  local matcher="${2}"

  tail_log "${logfile}" | while read line
  do 
    # this checks the line against the regular expression
    # and the result of the match (parts between ()) will
    # be stored in the BASH_REMATCH array
    [[ "${line}" =~ ${matcher} ]] && process_match "${line}"
  done
}

process_log /var/log/omxlog '(player_new|something_else)' &

process_log /some/other/log '(another_example)' &
```

Example text from running a test on my android phone

```
$> while sleep 5 ; do echo player_new >> test.txt ; done &
[2] 3110
$> tail -f test.txt | while read ; do [[ "${REPLY}" =~ player_new ]] && echo $(date) hello; done
Wed Feb 15 01:39:12 ACDT 2017 hello
Wed Feb 15 01:39:12 ACDT 2017 hello
Wed Feb 15 01:39:12 ACDT 2017 hello
Wed Feb 15 01:39:15 ACDT 2017 hello
Wed Feb 15 01:39:20 ACDT 2017 hello
^C
$>
```

This works on my phone, so I suspect the reason it's not working for you may be something to do with the raspberry pi which I can't help with sorry

Comment: I tried the first inline method, but unfortunately it doesn't work again. Just waiting. Maybe the problem is that I'm using putty to SSH into RPi !!? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it must be something to do with the raspberry pi yeah. I've added sample output above so you can see it working and compare to what you've got

Comment: This is a really long shot, but you might try running the command "sync" in another terminal and see if this causes the kernel to flush any IO buffers, maybe it is still buffered and not written to your log file yet I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Use print to print statements in awk. for more refer this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271856/why-does-print-work-with-awk-but-echo-doesnt).

For matching the string player_new use :

```
awk '$1 ~ /player_new/ {print $1}' /var/log/omxlog
```

To monitor continuously :

```
tail -f /var/log/omxlog | awk '$1 ~ /player_new/ {print $1}'
```

More of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001849/awk-partly-string-match-if-column-partly-matches).

Comment: first solution won't "follow" the file.

Comment: The first solution doesn't follow. The second solution doesn't work. Same thing that happens with my own tries.

Comment: 1. The $1 argument shown is just an example, in your logs please check the number and use same with '$' while running the command. You can change print to whatever you want.